# How to know command is installed in shell

Tags: shell

In xxx.sh, I need to execute a command. But if this command is not found, I want to throw an error.

```
if [[ xxxxxxx ]]; then
    echo "sorry xx command not found"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script):

In summary:

Where bash is your shell/hashbang, consistently use hash (for commands) or type (to consider built-ins & keywords).

When writing a POSIX script, use command -v.